# goBack() method is not working correctly in WKWebView in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview, back

I'm working in an app where I need to go back in webview on press of back button which was set by web itself.
From web, I'm getting a JS event when back is pressed and below is the code which I handle on click of back button in webview.

```
func goBackInWebView(_ webView: WKWebView?) {
    if webView?.canGoBack ?? false {
        webView?.goBack()
        return
    }
    close() //this line just dismisses/pops the controller based on the controller presentation.
 }
```

Now when I open any content in WebView, another page of WebView opens and the back button is visible. When I press the back button, the JS event is triggered and above function is called. But the back functionality is not working correctly.

- Pressing back button for the first time, nothing happens. (control goes into if condition `webView?.canGoBack ?? false`)
- Pressing back button for the second time, nothing happens. (control goes into if condition `webView?.canGoBack ?? false`)
- Pressing back button for the third time, controller closes. (control does not go into if condition `webView?.canGoBack ?? false`)

I checked other solutions on StackOverflow which suggested to use `webView.stopLoading()`, but that also doesn't work for me.

**Specifications:**

- Xcode: 14.1
- Test: iPhone 11 (15.0) (Simulator) (Note: This does not work even in device)

**EDIT*****

There was a requirement from the client that we have to pass the custom header in webview in every request (request made by us and request made by webview too).

So to solve this, I added the `decidePolicyFor` method to pass custom header to the request that webview made.

Below is the code for that.

```
override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        self.currentLoadedUrl = navigationAction.request.url
        let requestHeaders = navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
        if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated || navigationAction.navigationType == .backForward),
           requestHeaders["header_key1"] == nil || requestHeaders["header_key2"] == nil,
           let currentUrl = navigationAction.request.url,
           currentUrl != self.getInitialUrl() {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: currentUrl)
            request.setValue("header_value1", forHTTPHeaderField: "header_key1")
            request.setValue("header_value2", forHTTPHeaderField: "header_key2")
            webView.load(request)
        } else {
            return super.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        }
    }
```

These above conditions were added because custom headers were not working correctly in every subsequent request of a webview.

Now I assume that this can be the reason for the failure of back navigation of webview.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using WebKit,

> import WebKit

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self // Set the navigation delegate
    view.addSubview(webView)
    
    // Load your initial URL in the webView
    if let url = URL(string: "https://your-initial-url.com") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
```

And in

> WKNavigationDelegate

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .backForward {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack() // Go back in the WebView's navigation history
            decisionHandler(.cancel) // Cancel the default action
            return
        }
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow) // Allow the default action (i.e., load the new page)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul, thanks for your reply.
We will need to handle the back event which is triggered from web to get the action of back button and use all the logic there.
But I still tried your solution but that also isn't working for me. Same thing happens with your solution too.

Comment: Try this as a workaround to check whether JS is working properly or not.

webView?.evaluateJavaScript("window.history.back();", completionHandler: { _, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle any error that occurred while executing the JS code
            print("Error executing JS code: \(error)")
            return
        }

By using evaluateJavaScript, you are directly triggering the JS back event from your Swift code, and it might help overcome any inconsistencies caused by relying on the JS event being sent from the web content.

Comment: Use webView(_:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:) and webView(_:didFail:withError:) methods. These methods can provide additional information about any navigation-related issues.

Comment: Hi @Rahul. Sorry for the late response. I was away from keyboard. I've edited my question. I think there was lack of information earlier. Can you please check it now?